# How to check if a string is a number?

Tags: c, string

I want to check if a string is a number with this code. I must check that all the chars in the string are integer, but the while returns always isDigit = 1. I don't know why that if doesn't work.

```
char tmp[16];
scanf("%s", tmp);

int isDigit = 0;
int j=0;
while(j<strlen(tmp) && isDigit == 0){
  if(tmp[j] > 57 && tmp[j] < 48)
    isDigit = 0;
  else
    isDigit = 1;
  j++;
}
```

Comment: your range is wrong u want bigger than 57 and smaller than 48 .and it is impossible

Comment: The `scanf()` usage here is dangerous, as the input may overflow the `tmp` buffer.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Forget about ASCII code checks, use `isdigit` or `isnumber` (see [`man isnumber`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/all/3/isnumber/)). The first function checks whether the character is 0–9, the second one also accepts various other number characters depending on the current locale.

There may even be better functions to do the check – the important lesson is that this is a bit more complex than it looks, because the precise definition of a “number string” depends on the particular locale and the string encoding.

Comment: +1.  They might also want to consider `-` and `.` (depending on locale, of course)

Comment: `isdigit` and `isnumber` are very good functions. However, they are really bad if you want to learn exactly how to distinguish numbers from other characters. To learn the basics of a function, or more precie, how a function works, is more important than to learn how to use a function. To me this answer is correct but in no way helps the OP in the long run. He still doesn't know how to distinguish numbers in other languages that lack `isdigit` and `isnumber`. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: isnumber() is not standard C

Answer (score 13):

```
  if(tmp[j] >= '0' && tmp[j] <= '9') // should do the trick
```

Answer (score 8):

More obvious and simple, thread safe example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2){
        printf ("Dont' forget to pass arguments!\n");
        return(-1);
    }

    printf ("You have executed the program : %s\n", argv[0]);

    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++){
        if(strcmp(argv[i],"--some_definite_parameter") == 0){
            printf("You have passed some definite parameter as an argument. And it is \"%s\".\n",argv[i]);
        }
        else if(strspn(argv[i], "0123456789") == strlen(argv[i])) {
            size_t big_digit = 0;
            sscanf(argv[i], "%zu%*c",&big_digit);
            printf("Your %d'nd argument contains only digits, and it is a number \"%zu\".\n",i,big_digit);
        }
        else if(strspn(argv[i], "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz./") == strlen(argv[i]))
        {
            printf("%s - this string might contain digits, small letters and path symbols. It could be used for passing a file name or a path, for example.\n",argv[i]);
        }
        else if(strspn(argv[i], "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ") == strlen(argv[i]))
        {
            printf("The string \"%s\" contains only capital letters.\n",argv[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Gerhardh. You are right. My fault - copy-paste mistake.

Comment: I loved this method of identifying numerical strings. Brillaint!

Comment: this approach does not work for `"-1"` nor for `""`.

Comment: @chqrlie How could "" be passed as an argument of CLI?

Comment: Yes, to be honest, there is a lot of logical errors, but that source code just an draft example, which would be supplemented with logic for recognizing negative numbers, among other things.

Comment: @DennisV: empty strings cannot be entered via `scanf("%s",...)` but not a problem as command line arguments: type `./myprogram "" ''` at the shell prompt, both `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` will be empty strings.

Answer (score 4):

In this part of your code:

```
if(tmp[j] > 57 && tmp[j] < 48)
  isDigit = 0;
else
  isDigit = 1;
```

Your `if` condition will always be false, resulting in `isDigit` always being set to `1`.  You are probably wanting:

```
if(tmp[j] > '9' || tmp[j] < '0')
  isDigit = 0;
else
  isDigit = 1;
```

But, this can be simplified to:

```
isDigit = isdigit(tmp[j]);
```

However, the logic of your loop seems kind of misguided:

```
int isDigit = 0;
int j=0;
while(j<strlen(tmp) && isDigit == 0){
  isDigit = isdigit(tmp[j]);
  j++;
}
```

As `tmp` is not a constant, it is uncertain whether the compiler will optimize the length calculation out of each iteration.

As @andlrc suggests in a comment, you can instead just check for digits, since the terminating NUL will fail the check anyway.

```
while (isdigit(tmp[j])) ++j;
```

Comment: `for (char *ptmp = tmp; isdigit(*ptmp); ptmp++);` might be nicer.

Comment: @andlrc: Yes, that is leveraging `isdigit()` returning false for `'\0'`.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include "stdbool.h"
#include "stddef.h"
bool isNumber(char const* const text) {
    if (text == NULL || text[0] == '\0') {
        return false;
    }

    int dot_counter = 0;
    size_t length = 1;
    for (char character = text[1]; character != '\0';
         ++length, character = text[length]) {
        bool const is_valid_character =
            (character >= '0' && character <= '9') ||
            (character == '.' && ++dot_counter == 1);

        if (is_valid_character == false) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    char const first_character = text[0];
    bool is_character_sign = (first_character == '-' || first_character == '+');
    // verifications for first left character
    if ((is_character_sign || first_character == '.') && length == 1) {
        return false;
    }
    if (length == 2 && is_character_sign && text[1] == '.') {
        return false;
    }
    return (is_character_sign || first_character == '.') ||
           (first_character >= '0' && first_character <= '9');
}

#include <assert.h>
int main() {
    char tmp[16];
    assert(isNumber("a") == false);
    assert(isNumber("aa") == false);
    assert(isNumber("1"));
    assert(isNumber("11"));
    assert(isNumber("+1"));
    assert(isNumber("+1.") && +1. == 1.0);
    assert(isNumber("+.0") && +.0 == 0.0);
    assert(isNumber("-1"));
    assert(isNumber("-.0") && -.0 == -0.0);
    assert(isNumber("-1.") && -1. == -1.0);
    assert(isNumber("1.") && 1. == 1.0);
    assert(isNumber(".0") && .0 == 0.0);
    assert(isNumber(".") == false);
    assert(isNumber("-") == false);
    assert(isNumber("+") == false);
    assert(isNumber("+.") == false);
    assert(isNumber(".+") == false);
    assert(isNumber("-.") == false);
    assert(isNumber(".-") == false);
    assert(isNumber("") == false);
    assert(isNumber("1.1"));
    assert(isNumber("-1.1"));
    assert(isNumber("\0") == false);
    assert(isNumber(NULL) == false);

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/YdnM6TKaz

Comment: Checking for '\n' and '\r' might be useful

Comment: some problems: `isNumber("-1")` should return `true` and `isNumber("")` should return `false`

Comment: More remarks: `length` and `i` should have type `size_t` but the down loop must be written more carefully. `char character = text[length - 1];` has undefined behavior if `length` is `0`.

Comment: @chqrlie, code improved.

Comment: Code seems to work but can be simplified substantially. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77255444/4593267

Answer (score 3):

```
if ( strlen(str) == strlen( itoa(atoi(str)) ) ) {
    //its an integer
}
```

As atoi converts string to number skipping letters other than digits, if there was no other than digits its string length has to be the same as the original.
This solution is better than innumber() if the check is for integer.

Comment: Hi! Just came across your anwear, I'm learning C, so this might be dumb question, but I have a program where I malloc data into an array (`char *array[4]; array[0] = (char*)malloc(10);`). Then I read value into this allocated array position (`scanf("%s", array[0]);`) and then I try to use your code like this: (`strlen(array[0]) == strlen( itoa(atoi(array[0])) )`), however I get the following error: `error: too few arguments to function 'itoa'`. As I said before, I'm new to this stuff, so this might be obvious, but I have no idea how to fix it :/. Could you please exmplain this to me?

Comment: Alternatively, you can just use `strcmp` instead.

Comment: itoa() is not standard C, you can use printf() instead

Comment: This approach dows not work for `"a"`.

Answer (score 2):

I need to do the same thing for a project I am currently working on. Here is how I solved things:

```
/* Prompt user for input */
printf("Enter a number: ");

/* Read user input */
char input[255]; //Of course, you can choose a different input size
fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);

/* Strip trailing newline */
size_t ln = strlen(input) - 1;
if( input[ln] == '\n' ) input[ln] = '\0';

/* Ensure that input is a number */
for( size_t i = 0; i < ln; i++){
    if( !isdigit(input[i]) ){
        fprintf(stderr, "%c is not a number. Try again.\n", input[i]);
        getInput(); //Assuming this is the name of the function you are using
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach does not detect an empty string, and rejects negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

None of these deal appropriately with negative numbers or floating point numbers.

How about:

```
bool
is_realnumber(char *instring) {
  if (*instring != '-' && *instring != '.' && !isdigit(*instring)) return false;
  if (strspn(instring+1, "0123456789.") < strlen(instring+1)) return false;
  int c = 0;
  while (*instring) if (*instring++ == '.') if (++c > 1) return false;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: some problems: `is_realnumber("+1")` should return `true`. `is_realnumber(".")`, `is_realnumber("-")` and `is_realnumber("-.")` should return `false`

Answer (score 1):

I can extend Marcelo's answer supporting floating numbers also as following:

```
char isnumber(const char *str)
{
     int decpos = -1, pmpos = -1, engpos = strlen(str) - 1, epmpos = strlen(str) - 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    /* check if it is integer */
    if (str[i] > 47 && str[i] < 58)
      continue;
    /* check if it is decimal seperator and used once*/
    else if (str[i] == 46 && decpos == -1)
    {
      decpos = i;
      continue;
    }
    /* check if it is +/-, at the begining*/
    else if ((str[i] == 43 || str[i] == 45) && i == 0)
    {
      pmpos = 1;
      continue;
    }
    /* check if it is engineering format e/E, used once, after decimal and before +/-*/
    else if ((str[i] == 69 || str[i] == 101) && engpos == strlen(str) - 1 && i > 0 && i > decpos && i < epmpos)
    {
      engpos = 1;
      continue;
    }
    /* check if it is engineering format +/-, used once, after decimal and after engineering e/E*/
    else if ((str[i] == 43 || str[i] == 45) && epmpos == strlen(str) - 1 && i > 0 && i > decpos && i > engpos)
    {
      epmpos = 1;
      continue;
    }
    else
      return 0;
  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the function as following:

```
bool isNumeric(const char* s){
    while(*s){
        if(*s < '0' || *s > '9')
            return false;
        ++s;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You could also return `bool` for best practice.

Comment: @Maf you are right! Updated :)

Comment: There should be at least one digit: as posted `isNumeric("")` will return `true` incorrectly.  Also `isNumeric("-1")` should return `true` but does not.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to use that number in integer/long form in the future, you will be calling `atoi` or `atol` anyway, in which case you might want to just check the return value.

```
char tmp[16];
scanf("%s", tmp); // unsafe!!!
long tmp_long = atol(&tmp);
if (tmp_long == 0){
    printf("%s: is not a number.\n", &tmp);
}
```

[tutorialspoint on `atol`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atol.htm)

Comment: wth this logic, `"0"` would not be considered a number.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition says `if X is greater than 57 AND smaller than 48`. `X` cannot be both greater than 57 and smaller than 48 at the same time.

```
if(tmp[j] > 57 && tmp[j] < 48)
```

It should be `if X is greater than 57 OR smaller than 48`:

```
if(tmp[j] > 57 || tmp[j] < 48)
```

Answer (score 0):

rewrite the whole function as below:

```
bool IsValidNumber(char * string)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < strlen( string ); i ++)
   {
      //ASCII value of 0 = 48, 9 = 57. So if value is outside of numeric range then fail
      //Checking for negative sign "-" could be added: ASCII value 45.
      if (string[i] < 48 || string[i] > 57)
         return FALSE;
   }

   return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: You should never use magic numbers in code. Especially if they are completely unnecessary. Instead of `48` use `'0'` etc.. Also calling `strlen` in each iteration of the loop is causing extra execution time. You should move that call before the loop.

Comment: more problems: `IsValidNumber("-1")` should return `true` and `IsValidNumber("")` should return `false`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the result of your code "isDigit" is reflecting only the last digit test. As far as I understand your qustion, you want to return isDigit = 0 whenever you have any character that is not a number in your string. Following your logic, you should code it like this:

```
char tmp[16];
scanf("%s", tmp);

int isDigit = 0;
int j=0;
isDigit = 1;  /* Initialised it here */
while(j<strlen(tmp) && isDigit == 0){
  if(tmp[j] > 57 || tmp[j] < 48) /* changed it to OR || */
    isDigit = 0;
  j++;
}
```

To get a more understandable code, I'd also change the test:

```
if(tmp[j] > 57 || tmp[j] < 48)
```

to the following:

```
if(tmp[j] > '9' || tmp[j] < '0')
```

Comment: More problems  to report: `scanf("%s", tmp)` -> `scanf("%15s", tmp)` and `&& isDigit == 0` -> `&& isDigit != 0`

Answer (score 0):

Can check every char by isdigit().

```
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int is_digit_str(char* str){
    int digit_count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
      if(isdigit(str[i]))
         digit_count++;
      else
         break;
    }

    return digit_count == strlen(str);
}
```

Comment: There should be at least one digit: as posted `is_digit_str("")` will return `1` incorrectly.  Also `is_digit_str("-1")` should return `1` but does not.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could use this method, it uses the **isdigit()** function that you get from including the **ctype.h** library.

This piece of code checks if the return value of isdigit() is zero (it means that the character that we are analyzing is a non digit) if so, it increments j.

The logic is using the j variable as an "opcode": if not equal to zero it has been incremented hence, the function encountered a non digit char, otherwise every single char that is present in the string is a digit.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  char data[] = "1234t6789";
  int check;

  while(data[i] != '\0'){
    if((check = isdigit(data[i])) == 0)
      j++;
    i++;
  }

  if(j != 0)
    printf("The string doesn't contain just numbers.\n");
  else printf("The string contains only numbers.\n");
  
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple self contained function that verifies if a character string represents a number with an optional sign, at least one digit and an optional decimal point:

```
int isNumber(const char *str) {
    size_t index = 0;
    int has_digits = 0, has_dot = 0;
    char cc;

    // reject null pointer
    if (!str) {
        return 0;
    }
    // skip optional sign
    if (*str == '+' || *str == '-') {
        index++;
    }
    // scan the string
    while ((cc = str[index++]) != '\0') {
        if (cc == '.') {
            // accept a single decimal point
            if (has_dot++)
                return 0;
        } else
        if (cc >= '0' && cc <= '9') {
            // we have at least one digit
            has_digits = 1;
        } else {
            // reject all other characters
            return 0;
        }
    }
    // must have at least one digit
    return has_digits;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int being_number(char string[]){
int l=strlen(string);
for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
{
    if(string[i] >= '0' && string[i] <= '9'){
        i=i; 
    }
    else{
        return(0);
    }
}
return(1);
```

}

Comment: `i=i;` ? Really? Surely you can think of something less wonky than that.

Comment: There should be at least one digit: as posted `being_number("")` will return `true` incorrectly.  Also `being_number("-1")` should return `1`.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the simplest possible answer:

```
bool isnumber(char string[]) {
    int len = strlen(string);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < len)
    {
            if (isdigit(string[i]) == 0)
                    return false;

            i++;
    }

    return true; }
```

Comment: You should cast the `char` argument to `isdigit()` as `(unsigned char)` to avoid undefined behavior on negative `char` values on platforms where `char` is a signed type.

Comment: You should accept an initial `'+'` or `'-'` sign.

Comment: `i` and `len` should have type `size_t` and the argument `string` should be defined as `const char string[]` or `const char *string`.

Comment: There should be at least one digit: as posted `isnumber("")` will return `true` incorrectly.

Comment: It's not the _simplest possible_ answer.  And it has no need to make two passes through the string.  And you're passing possibly-signed `char` to a `<ctype.h>` function.