# read argv[1] into say "key" using atoi. Should only accept int. If a non int like 3g is entered how do I reject is as non int

Tags: c, int, argv

How do I fix this. My program must not accept any alphabet.

Int must accept only valid numbers and reject the string if it contains a alphabet

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char str[1000];
    int i, ch, key;
    {
        if (argc != 2)
        {
             printf("key\n");
             return 1; // exit prog
        }
        // read argv value into key after argc valid
        //to prevent sementation error
        key = atoi(argv[1]);
        // do multi wrap arounds use leftover digit
        key = (key % 26);
            //check for positive number
        if (key < 1)
        {
        printf("key\n");
        return 1; // exit prog
        }
        // ask for text if pos number
        else if (key >= 0)
        {
        printf("text:");
        // check string and read in
        fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);
        i = strlen(str);
}
```

If I type

- ./name (no input, alphabet, two strings returns 1 as it should.)
- ./name (number should work and return 0)
- ./name a1 or b5 return 1 but 1a or 5b return 0 and should not.

In the debugger I can see it only reads the value of the number into argv as 1 or 5 not as 1a or 5b

Comment: First, don't use `atoi()` on unchecked input - it has absolutely no error checking.  It returns an `int` no matter what you pass into it, and it has no way of returning an error if the input wasn't a numeric value.

Comment: [`isdigit()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isdigit) can help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a string is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644906/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-number)

Comment: @Cid `isdigit()` can be helpful, but your usage is wrong.

Comment: @MikeCAT oh yeah it takes a single character

Comment: The "key" must read in the value of argv for an up to  int only if the int is valid (2^31).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the function `atoi` use another standard function `strtol`. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s1 = "3g";
    const char *s2 = "32";
    
    char *endptr;

    errno = 0;
    
    long key = strtol( s1, &endptr, 10 );
    if ( *endptr != '\0' || errno != 0 )
    {
        puts( "invalid value supplied" );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "key = %ld\n", key );
        
    }

    endptr = NULL;
    errno = 0;
    
    key = strtol( s2, &endptr, 10 );
    if ( *endptr != '\0' || errno != 0 )
    {
        puts( "invalid value supplied" );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "key = %ld\n", key );
        
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
invalid value supplied
key = 32
```

Comment: Corner: `if ( *endptr != '\0' || errno != 0 )` does not detect `s1` as `""`, yet that is a little tricky to pass into `main()` anyways.  Perhaps `if (s1 == endptr ||  *endptr != '\0' || errno != 0 ) `?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica It is the way how atoi is defined. atoi: (int)strtol(nptr, (char **)NULL, 10)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I have updated the code substituting int key; for long key;

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`strtol()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) to convert strings to integers and obtain the last position of converted string.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

// ...

int key;
// ...
char* end;
long key_temp;
// ...
errno = 0;
key_temp = strtol(argv[1], &end, 10);
if (argv[1][0] == '\0') {
    // no character exists
} else if (*end != '\0') {
    // invalid character exists
} else if ((errno == ERANGE && (key_temp == LONG_MIN || key_temp == LONG_MAX)) ||
key_temp < INT_MIN || INT_MAX < key_temp) {
    // too small or too big
} else if (key_temp == 0 && errno != 0) {
    // other error
} else {
    // looks OK
    key = (int)key_temp;
}
```

Comment: The expression `key_temp < LONG_MIN || LONG_MAX < key_temp` is always false (given the type of `key_temp` is `long`)

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Thank you, fixed.

Comment: Still not guaranteed to work as intended: It might be that `LONG_MIN == INT_MIN` and `LONG_MAX == INT_MAX`. There are some platforms that these are true. The expression will be always false on such platforms.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin fixed.

Comment: `(errno == ERANGE && (key_temp == LONG_MIN || key_temp == LONG_MAX))` is unclear.  Why not use `(errno == ERANGE)` instead and skip the `key_temp == ...` tests?

Comment: `else if (key_temp == 0 && errno != 0)` is also unclear.  Why not simplify to `else if (errno != 0)`.  I see no C spec requiring the return value as 0 on some other error.

Comment: //I did not want to rewrite my code from start so: I added the following into my code just before the "key = atoi(argv[1]);" line                                                                               else if(strspn(argv[1], "0123456789") == strlen(argv[1])) {
         }    else if(strspn(argv[1], "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ./") == strlen(argv[1]))
        {  printf("key\n");
            return 1; }

Answer (score 0):

```
   //I did not want to rewrite my code from start so: I added the following into my 
   //code just before the "key = atoi(argv[1]);" line

                                                                 
     else if(strspn(argv[1], "0123456789") == strlen(argv[1]))
     {
     }   
     else if(strspn(argv[1], "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ./") == strlen(argv[1]))
    {  printf("key\n");
        return 1; }
```