# Possible to sanitise command line arguments in argv?

Tags: c

I'm currently learning C and I'm messing around with command line inputs from the user.

I understand that argc is the count, i.e. the amount of entered commands, and argv is an array of what was entered.

I know how to check to see if the user entered a value after the called program with argc > 1 etc, and I know that argv takes string type variables which I can convert to real integers using atoi(). However I'm not sure how to implicitly only accepts integers. I've tried using isdigit etc around argv but I usually end up with a segment error. Is there a way around this?

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2 && //code to ensure argv[1] is int)  
    {
         //code
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a string is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644906/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-number)

Comment: What do you mean by "implicitly"? There certainly is no way to make the shell guarantee. What keeps you from reading and ignoring/rejecting what is not correct? Reading as string and the parsing with multiple attempts of `sscanf()` is the way to do that.

Comment: Excluding `0` from the set of valid integers, you can just do: `int i; if (argc == 2 && (i = atoi(argv[1]))) { ...`. If you need the `0` go for `strtol()`.

Comment: _"I've tried using isdigit..."_: that may be a good start, but you didn't show us the offending code, so it's hard to help you with that.

Comment: @alk `atoi` is able to convert a `const char*` to an integer even if it contains text. For instance `atoi(" -123junk")` returns -123 while " -123junk" is not a number. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi

Comment: @Pierre: You are right. As I never use `atoi()`, but only `strtol()` I forgot this.

Comment: @alk & jabberwocky this is the code, but it only follows the else path.                       `int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    int x;
    if (argc == 2 && (x = isdigit(atoi(argv[1]))))`

Comment: This `isdigit(atoi(...))` should make the compiler issue a warning. If it does not then raise the compiler's warning level. Then fix all  warnings until no more warnings  are issued. Do not blindly cast away warnings.

Comment: @Pierre - You make a good point regarding the ability of `atoi()` to convert a string that contains trailing non-numeric values, but because OP is looking to _sanitise_ the input, such arguments could also be considered undesirable, and therefore explicitly  filtered.

Answer (score 0):

*"...not sure how to implicitly only accepts integers."*

This is not implicitly done, you have to *explicitly* test each string for its contents.

Using functions in the string test category, for example [isdigit](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isdigit.htm), walk through each of the `argv` string arguments, i.e from `argv[1]` through `argv[argc - 1]` and test the character type to ensure it is a numeric value, from `0` to `9` and `-`.  (Note: other valid numeric `char` symbols can included, eg: `e`, `x`,et.al. but are not in this limited example.)

A simple example:

given command line: `prog.exe 23 45 1f4 -57`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for(int i=1;i<argc;i++)
    {
        if(!test_argv(argv[i]))
        {
            //notify user of wrong input, and exit
            printf("argv[%d] contains non numeric value.  Exiting\n", i);
        }
    }
    //continue with program
    return 0;
}


bool test_argv(const char *buf)
{
    while(*buf)
    {
        if((!isdigit(*buf)) && (*buf != '-'))
        {
            return false;
        }
        buf++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Results in:
[image]